# Creating a jar file with map reduce program on windows and then running it on linux (hadoop)

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, jar

i'm usually using windows, but for `hadoop` im using `ubuntu` (in oracle VM) i was wondering wherever its possible to create in netbeans a jar, that contains compiled  mapper/reducer/java program that executes it, on windows environment and then launch that `jar` on Linux environment?

I know this is probably a beginners question, but i just didn't mange to find stuff on this issue on the web

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java bytecode is platform-independent.  Java classes compiled on Windows can run on Linux.  You don't have to do anything special; just build the jar, copy it into your Linux VM, and run it.

Comment: Thanks, since developing the java code can be quit inconvenient it Ubuntu (or maybe im just not used to it)